# Discover where are my USB speakers (device)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, debian, device, udev

I'm running Debian Sid and I want to know where are my USB speakers in system. For example: When I plug my pen drive, dmesg shows where it is (sda, sdb, etc). But when I plug my USB Speakers, it doesn't show anything:

```
[12032.284042] usb 2-2: new full speed USB device using ohci_hcd and address 2
[12032.497098] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0d8c, idProduct=0103
[12032.497103] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[12032.497107] usb 2-2: Product: USB Sound Device        
[12032.497109] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: C-Media INC.
[12032.497266] usb 2-2: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
```

How could I discover where it is? Is there a command to show devices connected?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

It's added as the next available ALSA card.

```
cat /proc/asound/cards
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to diff the listing of /dev before and after the device is connected.

Comment: How could I do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

(Oops, I see that I probably misunderstood the question. Sorry. I'll leave my answer in case it's remotely useful).

Try `lsusb`. It gives you an overview of USB devices connected.

Comment: lsusb -v doesn't show where is my device. I didn't find it. Thank you.